# input text to cmd.exe running in background using Java

Tags: java, android, cmd

I'm trying to use adb to send repetitive touch events to android so I need to entering the same codes to cmd.exe again and again like "adb shell input tap 50 50".

This is easily done by a Robot class in java if I just leave my computer there and let it control my keyboard and put the cmd window active, however I want to make my program to input the code to cmd while I'm doing my own stuff, meaning cmd is running in background but it can still get input and run.

Is it possible? If it is, how is it achieved? Does runtime.exec help?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running the whole thing in a virtual Box, and I can do my work outside the box...